# Doctrine creates new row when editing entity from cache

Tags: php, doctrine

I have retrieved a simple (no joins) serialised entity from a Redis cache.

When I edit this entity and call `persist()` and `flush()` on the entity manager, a new row is inserted instead of updating the existing entity.

The Doctrine documentation only seems to mention calling `merge()` with the entity but that fetches the item from the database which defeats the purpose of caching it.

How can I make the entity manager track this restored entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do need to call `merge()` - this is just so that the EntityManager is properly aware of the entity.  If you serialise the entity and then load it back up in a new session then the EntityManager now only knows the type and the attributes - it doesn't know if it has been previously saved to the database etc, which is why it just assumes it is new and creates a new row unless merged.

The EntityManager has an internal list of what's been saved, what's pending etc; it needs all this info to correctly do it's job - these details are not stored in the entities themselves. An unserialised entity read from cache is considered "unmanaged".

From the [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html) on this:

> In Doctrine an entity objects has to be “managed” by an EntityManager
>   to be updateable. Entities saved into the session are not managed in
>   the next request anymore. This means that you have to register these
>   entities with an EntityManager again if you want to change them or use
>   them as part of references between other entities. You can achieve
>   this by calling EntityManager#merge().

It doesn't completely defeat the purpose of caching it, because really you only need to merge at the point that you want to save back to the database.